# Repaint() method does not repaint what is needed

Tags: java, random, paintcomponent, repaint

This is what my task is.

I have to generate 4 random cards. After which, when pressing the Refresh button, the cards should randomize again. I have implemented the repaint() method like so but it does not change how the cards appear.

```
public class FourCards extends JFrame {

        JLabel slot1 = new JLabel(getImage());
        JLabel slot2 = new JLabel(getImage());
        JLabel slot3 = new JLabel(getImage());
        JLabel slot4 = new JLabel(getImage());

    public FourCards() {

        JPanel CardsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,4,5,5));
        add(CardsPanel);

        CardsPanel.add(slot1);
        CardsPanel.add(slot2);
        CardsPanel.add(slot3);
        CardsPanel.add(slot4);

        JButton jbtRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");

        JPanel ButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(ButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        ButtonPanel.add(jbtRefresh);

        jbtRefresh.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        }

    public ImageIcon getImage() {

        ImageIcon temp = new ImageIcon("C:/resized/" + (int)(Math.random() * 52) + ".png");
        return temp;

    }

    public void update() {

        slot1 = new JLabel(getImage());
        slot2 = new JLabel(getImage());
        slot3 = new JLabel(getImage());
        slot4 = new JLabel(getImage());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FourCards frame = new FourCards();
            frame.setTitle("Random 4 cards");
            frame.setSize(600,280);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            update(); // get new images
            repaint();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What you've done is roughtly equivilant to "put water in 4 buckets", "put all four buckets of water in a well". Later; "Add poison to buckets" and being suprised when the well isn't poisoned. Remember a variable is just a place to store something, nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `update()` method you are creating new `JLabel` objects and those objects are not added to the panel so they won't be displayed. To change the images use the `setIcon(...)` method on all `JLabel`s instead of creating new objects.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked marvelously. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
slot1 = new JLabel(getImage());
slot2 = new JLabel(getImage());
slot3 = new JLabel(getImage());
slot4 = new JLabel(getImage());
```

you're not changing the GUI. You're updating the values of the `slotX` variables. You should also replace the actual components in the GUI tree.

Try making `CardsPanel` a member variable, and do

```
CardsPanel.removeAll();
CardsPanel.add(new JLabel(getImage()));
CardsPanel.add(new JLabel(getImage()));
CardsPanel.add(new JLabel(getImage()));
CardsPanel.add(new JLabel(getImage()));
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `update()` method, you are creating new  `JLabel`s, but not adding them to the panel, and leaving the old ones on the panel unchanged. You have to change the existing  `JLabel`s and there's no need to create new ones. Like this:

```
public void update() {
    slot1.setIcon(getImage());
    slot2.setIcon(getImage());
    slot3.setIcon(getImage());
    slot4.setIcon(getImage());
}
```